# Is it possible to directly send an Api POST Request from Salesforce's QCP to a third-party API using JSForce?

Tags: javascript, api, salesforce, apex-code, jsforce

I am new to Salesforce CPQ, but I have done Salesforce Rest API integrations before.

The requirement is to send record from quoteLine items from the QCP to an external API to retrieve certain data and update the quoteline field in realtime.

Will it be possible to do it without using Apex Rest Api?

I have previously designed it to pass record.id from the QCP to an Apex Class and make API callouts from there and after getting the response passing it to the QCP to update the field. But using this design may cause it to hit Api limits in the future.

Comment: What is QCP? or is it a typo?